# How do I move an entire intranet site from SharePoint Foundation 2010 to a new SharePoint Server 2013 single server farm?

Tags: 2013, 2010, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, migration

I just walked into a new job, and the first thing I'm hit with is a SharePoint Foundation 2010 intranet site that has to remove from the server to a physically separate server for security reasons.

The new server already has SharePoint Server 2013 installed, and is using a separate MS SQL 2012 database.  Any ideas on how to go about this?

Comment: Hi , Please don't forget to **Mark** and **Upvote** the correct answer as accepted in case it helped and solved your issue to be helpful for future visitors. If you still need additional clarification don't hesitate to ask answer owner to help you or update your question with more details! Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

To upgrade from SharePoint 2010 Products to SharePoint 2013, you use the `database-attach method` to upgrade.

In the `database-attach method`, you first

- [Checklist for database-attach upgrade (SharePoint 2013)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607663.aspx) , This checklist helps you confirm that you follow all the steps that you must follow as you prepare for upgrade, perform the upgrade, and perform post-upgrade steps.
- Create and configure a SharePoint 2013 farm that you already have.
- Then you Copy / Backup the content and service application databases from the SharePoint 2010 Products farm, via SQL Management Studio
- Then attach and Restore and upgrade the databases.
- Then upgrade site collections.

[image]

- Finally , Migrate the SharePoint custom solutions by following the instructions at [How to Migrate a SharePoint 2010 Solution to 2013](https://threewill.com/how-to-migrate-a-sharepoint-2010-solution-to-2013/)

For the detail steps check

- [upgrade process to SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262483.aspx)
- [Restore / Migrate a SharePoint Web Application to another farm from SQL Database Backup](https://blog.devoworx.net/2014/07/17/sql-server-backup-restore-instead-of-a-stsadm-backup-restore-in-sharepoint-2010/)
- Or download the Microsoft Reference from [SharePoint 2013 Upgrade Process](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30371)